# Critério para desempatar lista no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma lista que vem com dados de outras planilhas. Faça um MAIOR para voltar o 1º maior, e depois o 2º e assim por diante. Depois faço  um `PROCV` para pegar o nome referente a esse valor. Até aí OK.

O problema e a dúvida: Como desempatar porque se por que se por exemplo tiverem 2 valores 18 com nomes diferentes, ele só pega o nome do maior.

Há algum jeito de resolver isso? Outra coisa: dentro desse arquivo tem várias planilhas (ano1, ano2, ano3) tem como colocar esse nome da planilha (que fica em baixo) numa célula, usando como referência alguma informação da mesma?

Sei que são duas dúvidas, mas o principal é o desempate, caso seja possível. Uso Excel 2016. Desde já agradeço aos que puderem ajudar.

Comment: Olá Ricardo, seria interessante colocar um exemplo para mostrar melhor o problema. Como não é um programa pode ser uma imagem, ou até uma tabela

Comment: [edit] sua pergunta e coloque a sua formula do `procv`, e um exemplo de suas listas

Comment: Seja bem-vindo(a). Por favor faça o [tour], depois leia [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e crie um [mcve] para a pergunta. Pois a pergunta está muito ampla e quando [você é mais específico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104), há mais chances de sua pergunta ser respondida corretamente.